# posrgresql: Confusion With Running Total of a Column

Tags: postgresql

Now, similar questions have been asked several times in this forum, but, I've been struggling with calculating the monthly, running sum of a column in a `posrgresql (Version 9.4.2)` table:

```
created_at           |  points
-----------------------------
2015-12-10 12:26:34  |  199
2016-01-10 12:26:34  |  199
2016-02-10 12:26:34  |  199
2016-03-10 12:26:34  |  500
2016-03-10 12:26:39  |  199
```

The expected result is:

```
created_at           |  sum
-----------------------------
2015-12-01           |  199
2016-01-01           |  398
2016-02-01           |  597
2016-03-01           |  1296
```

The working `sql` I arrived at, mostly through trial and error after reading the other threads, is:

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('month',created_at)::date as month_created, 
    sum(sum(points)) 
OVER 
    (
        ORDER BY date_trunc('month',created_at)::date
    ) 
FROM 
    point_histories
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

My confusion is why doesn't the following (which I'm obviously misunderstanding) work?

```
SELECT 
    month_created, 
    sum(points), 
    sum(sum(points)) 
OVER 
    (
        PARTITION BY month_created 
        ORDER BY created_at
    ) 
    AS cum_amt
FROM   
    (
        SELECT 
            *, 
            date_trunc('month', created_at)::date as month_created 
        FROM 
            point_histories
    ) 
    as derivedTable
ORDER  BY created_at
GROUP BY month_created
```

Above gives the following error:

```
********* Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 314
```

If I remove the `GROUP BY` clause, I get:

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "derivedtable.month_created" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the order by clause should finish your query.

```
SELECT 
    month_created, 
    sum(points), 
    sum(sum(points)) 
OVER 
    (
        PARTITION BY month_created 
        ORDER BY created_at
    ) 
    AS cum_amt
FROM   
    (
        SELECT 
            *, 
            date_trunc('month', created_at)::date as month_created 
        FROM 
            point_histories
    ) 
    as derivedTable
GROUP BY month_created
ORDER  BY created_at
```

Comment: That gives `ERROR:  column "derivedtable.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @CodePoet I never work with 'over' but I tested here with postgres 9.3 and a normal query ... I got your error if group and order wasn't in right order ... I will edit my answer to illustrate